# Iframe keep Printing Last PDF

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf, iframe

Print button is working perfect in debug mode. When implemented to server it's keep printing first document printed.

PDF file generate with new print page (if check PDF manually at server folder) but iframe is keep printing old page. It doesn't take new PDF from server.

Can someone help me here. I'm new to ASP.net

a.aspx

```
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Width="334px"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrint_Click" runat="server" Height="20px" Text="Print From Here" Width="183px" OnClick="btnPrint_Click_Click" ForeColor="Red" />
        <div title="print report">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvViewer" runat="server" ShowParameterPrompts="false" AsyncRendering="true" 
            Width="100%" BackColor="#F7F6F3" ShowRefreshButton="true" Height="800px" ToolTip="Click the arrow to Sort" >
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>               
        </div>
    </form>

    <iframe id="frmPrint" name="IframeName" width="500" 
        height="200" runat="server" 
        style="display: none">
   </iframe>
```

a.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnPrint_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamids;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string extension;

    byte[] bytes = rvViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType,
                   out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);


    FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("output.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    fs.Close();

    //Open exsisting pdf
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("output.pdf"));

    //Getting a instance of new pdf wrtiter
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(
       HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Print.pdf"), FileMode.CreateNew));
    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

    int i = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
    Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

    float width = psize.Width;
    float height = psize.Height;

    //Add Page to new document
    while (i < n)
    {
        document.NewPage();
        p++;
        i++;

        PdfImportedPage page1 = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
        cb.AddTemplate(page1, 0, 0);
    }


    //Attach javascript to the document
    PdfAction jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
    writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);
    document.Close();

    //Attach pdf to the iframe
    frmPrint.Attributes["src"] = "Print.pdf";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of caching.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me..!! How do i avoid that..

Comment: Give the file a unique name, plus won't the pattern you are doing now result in multiple people overwriting the same file?

Comment: Any example or further details will be appreciate.

Comment: instead of `frmPrint.Attributes["src"] = "Print.pdf";` you can use a guid value for the name:
`frmPrint.Attributes["src"] = string.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid());`